# How to query embedded array of objects based on conditions in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have an array of objects embedded in a document and there are multiple such documents in an collection.
How to do I query those embedded array of objects with below conditions(based on the documents I have below).

1. First get objects whose `"status"` is `"active"`(status will not be in all the objects but only few)
2. Then get the `"parent_user_id"` of the above satisfied object and match it with the rest of the objects `"parent_user_id"` and get those objects
3. the result of the above conditions have to set instead of the original Array (i.e: `"users"`) of objects in the output instead of all the objects present.
   So if you take a look at the result am expecting there are 3 elements missing from the user array because those elements did not satisfy the above conditions.
   Document I have in collection(there will be multiple document as such)

   ```
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("63a8808652f40e1d48a3d1d7"),
       "name" : "A",
       "description" : null,
       "users" : [
           {
               "id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
               "owner" : "John Doe",
               "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
               "status" : "active",
               "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
               "recent_items": ["tomato",onion]
           },
           {
               "id" : "63a880a552f40e1d48a3d1dc",
               "owner" : "John Doe 1",
               "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
               "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
               "recent_items": ["onion"]
           },
           {
               "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48assddd"
               "owner" : "John Doe 2",
               "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
               "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
           },
           {
               "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207"
               "owner" : "John Doe 11",
               "dt" : "2022-12-25,
               "status" : "inactive",
               "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207",
           },
           {
               "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb"
               "owner" : "John Doe 112",
               "dt" : "2022-12-25,
               "status" : "active",
               "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb",
               "recent_items": ["tomato"]
           }
           {
               "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg"
               "owner" : "John SS",
               "dt" : "2022-12-25,
               "status" : "inactive",
               "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg",
           }
           {
               "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d487777"
               "owner" : "John SS",
               "dt" : "2022-12-25,
               "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg",
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

Result am expecting

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("63a8808652f40e1d48a3d1d7"),
  "name" : "A",
  "description" : null,
        "users" : [
            {
                "id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
                "owner" : "John Doe",
                "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
                "status" : "active",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
                "recent_items": ["tomato",onion]
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880a552f40e1d48a3d1dc",
                "owner" : "John Doe 1",
                "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
                "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48assddd"
                "owner" : "John Doe 2",
                "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
                "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb"
                "owner" : "John Doe 112",
                "dt" : "2022-12-25,
                "status" : "active",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb",
                "recent_items": ["tomato"]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use some `$filter` stages as follows :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      users_matched: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          as: "user",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "active",
              "$$user.status"
            ],
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $set: {
      users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          as: "user",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$user.parent_user_id",
              "$users_matched.id"
            ],
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unset: "users_matched"
  }
])
```

You can check for yourself on mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/SrpsWb4v21x

**EDIT TO ANSWER THE SECOND QUESTION:**

You could fix your tomato problem as follows :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      active_users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          as: "user",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "active",
              "$$user.status"
            ],
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      tomato_users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          as: "user",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "tomato",
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$$user.recent_items",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ],
            
          },
          
        },
        
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $set: {
      users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          as: "user",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $in: [
                  "$$user.parent_user_id",
                  "$active_users.id"
                ],
                
              },
              {
                $in: [
                  "$$user.parent_user_id",
                  "$tomato_users.parent_user_id"
                ],
                
              }
            ]
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "active_users",
      "tomato_users"
    ]
  }
])
```

See on mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/mb21UT475yt

Comment: the above solution worked, thanks. But have another question.
I have modified the documents and result am expecting accordingly. If you check there's an extra element called `"recent_items"`. So my question is, will it be possible to fetch the results for the 2 conditions getting satisfied and at the same time any one of the objects as a result from the 2 conditions should have `"tomato"` under the `"recent_items"` array?
I have modified the result accordingly as well.

Comment: can you please help me out here with the above query?@Fourchette

Comment: I'm not sure about the condition you want to match here. If the parent must have `tomato` it will be pretty simple (just add a `$and` operator in my first cond, with {$in:["tomato", "$$user.recent_items"]}). 

But if it's the parent or any child should have `tomato` it will be harder.

Comment: yes, the parent or any child should have tomato in it. I tried your query and modified it all the way possible to make it work for it but did not work.

Comment: Just edited my previous answer to fix this issue of yours. If this fix your problem please vote up + accept it.